# How to interrupt a thread onBackPressed without crashing?

Tags: android, splash-screen, java-threads

I have tried overriding onBackPressed to not only finish the current activity but also to interrupt the thread as I am calling an intent to the next activity within. When I pressed back before, the splash activity finished, but the thread kept running and call the intent to the next activity. Now that I've include the thread interruption onBackPressed,the app crashes when I press back. What am I doing wrong?

```
skipscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences savestate = getSharedPreferences("skip", MODE_PRIVATE);
            savestate.edit().putBoolean("skip", true).apply();
            skip= true;
            homeintent();
        }
    });
    Thread splashthread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    if (!skip) { homeintent();}
                } catch (InterruptedException Interrupt) {
                    Interrupt.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    };
    splashthread.start();
}
private void homeintent() {
    Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, home.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    splashthread.interrupt();
    finish();
  }
}
```

UPDATED: (This solution has worked for me).

```
skipscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences savestate = getSharedPreferences("skip", MODE_PRIVATE);
            savestate.edit().putBoolean("skip", true).apply();
            skip= true;
            homeintent();
        }
    });
    Thread splashthread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    if (!skip) { homeintent();}
                } catch (InterruptedException Interrupt) {
                    Interrupt.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    };
    splashthread.start();
}
private void homeintent() {
    if (!ThreadInterrupted) {
           Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, home.class);
           startActivity(i);
   }
           finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        SharedPreferences savestate= getSharedPreferences("ThreadInterrupted", MODE_PRIVATE);
        savestate.edit().putBoolean("ThreadInterrupted", true).apply();
        ThreadInterrupted = true;
        homeintent();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try a simple null check in `homeintent()` , i.e.  `if(splash.this!=null)`  ?

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: `spashthread` reference is local to the onClickListener.  You need to assign it to the global reference and put a nullpointer check like @Droidekas said.

Comment: I just noticed,but I dont think your code will compile.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, @Droidekas, but probably I am missing something. It actually compiled (Note that I simplified the elements names before posting the question so other learners can find it easier to navigate through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a succint answer as well as to explain how to do this in the future,take a look at the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class and the [Handler.postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method.

```
 private Handler homeIntenthandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){

    //other things
        skipscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences savestate = getSharedPreferences("skip", MODE_PRIVATE);
                savestate.edit().putBoolean("skip", true).apply();
                skip= true;
                homeintent();
            }
        });

//initialise handler and set timer;
        homeIntenthandler= new Handler();
        homeIntenthandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               homeintent();
            }
        },3000);
    }
    }
    private void homeintent() {
        Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, home.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if(homeIntenthandler!=null)
        homeIntenthandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        finish();
      }
    }
```

the `Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` is based on the documentation given for the [same](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Do you think it's a better idea to use a handler rather than a thread for a splash screen? Your code looks perfectly correct. By the way, what do you think about the updated code? Is it accurate?

Comment: A handler is meant for these sort of purposes. And yes the updated code will work. But you are maintaining a lot of u necessary code like shared preferences and savedstate which can be avoided.

Comment: I think you're right. Let me try it and I will get back to the question solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you call interrupt() method on your thread, while in sleep, an InterruptedException will be thrown.

You can check inside your thread weather it should continue:

```
 Thread splashthread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           while (shouldContinue) {
                  doSomeWork();
           }
   }
};
```

You can then change shouldContinue to false in your onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       shouldContinue = false;
       finish();
}
```

Comment: I tried this way and even added an additional shared preference to save the boolean state, but no luck.

Comment: There's no need to use SharedPreferences. Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: Actually, I just solved it by changing your idea in some things. I will post the edit in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Udi I has answered your question.
But i refer you to use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead of Thread.

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timertask;
timer = new Timer();
timertask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               homeintent();        
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(timertask, 3000);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(timertask!=null){
        timertask.cancel();
    }
    if(timer!=null){
        timer.cancel();
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Timer sometimes is not a good choice as android says 'If there is a currently running task it is not affected", which means if a loop is going on, Timer will not be canceled until and unless loop complete its execution. But by using thread and placing boolean check inside loop we can tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **volatile** `boolean` check to stop thread from progressing, see following code:

```
private volatile boolean cancelled = false;

Thread splashthread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            if ( cancelled ) {
              return; // or handle this however you want
            }else{
              // do what ever you want to do here
            }
        }
};
splashthread.start();
```

And in `onBackPressed` do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    cancelled = true;
    finish();
}
```

The **volatile keyword is recommended** because, generally, the thread doing the cancelling not necessarily will be the same thread that is being cancelled. Marking `boolean` check as `volatile` ensures that the thread checking the flag will see the up to date value.

Comment: I used a volatile boolean for the updated solution (just didn't post the whole code). Thanks!